# Linq searches for recent birthdays (within 15 days)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How to use Linq
A table
Field Birthday
Linq searches for recent birthdays (within 15 days)
from a in Employee where a.PositionStatus == true select new{ a.Name,a.Birthday}

Comment: `where a.PositionStuats==true && a.Birthday < Datetime.Now.AddDays(15)`

Comment: This is just to find out people who were born this year. People who were born every year have

Comment: Compare month and day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query

```
var fromdate = DateTime.Now;
var todate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
 var result =
 (
 from a in Employee
 where a.PositionStuats==true && a.DateOfBirth.Value.Month >= fromdate.Month && 
 a.DateOfBirth.Value.Month <= todate.Month &&
 a.DateOfBirth.Value.Day >= fromdate.Day && a.DateOfBirth.Value.Day <= todate.Day
 select new{ a.Name,a.Birthday}
 ).ToList();
```

Depending on your `entity frame work version` you can also replace `a.DateOfBirth.Value.Month` with `a.DateOfBirth.Month`.